# удаление записи в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Имею такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу по нажатию удалять запись в базе данных.Как указать базе номер записи которую я хочу удалить. Для примера пробовал удалять так но тоже ничего не вышло.

```
Query applesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("event").orderByChild("title").equalTo("TITLE");

            applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас записи загружаются в список recyclerview, в своё время я делал как-то вот так:

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new 
        RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), mRecyclerView, new 
        RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
            DatabaseReference dat = mAdapter.getRef(position);
            dat.removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Удалено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
```

mAdapter здесь это это инициализированный и настроенный FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
Обрабатывание нажатий на элемент recyclerview в этом примере происходит с помощью класса RecyclerItemClickListener. [Его можно взять отсюда, второй ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick). Добавьте его в проект.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Но зачем "костыли" с RecyclerView?Если в холдере можно спокойно повесить слушатель на нажатие и брать позицию с помощью метода getAdapterPosition.

Comment: @UjinUkr Я уже и не помню, зачем решил сделать так :D